# How to split header of some columns on their two subcolumns for a table?

Tags: tables, formatting, header-footer, multicolumn

let us consider my table
[image: my_table]
I want to reorganize the header in this way: for column 3, I want to delete the dash and split the words "id." and "PDes" on two subcolumns. For the successive columns (from 4 to 7) the meaning of data is that they are all functions, i.e. DVmin=DVmin(TOF), TOFmin=TOFmin(DV) and so on for the other two. I tought to split these couples of variables (and their units) on their two subcolumns and then to delete the dash. Do you think that is readable? If yes, can you show how to split the variables on two subcolumns?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Simulation results for $\Delta V < \SI{500}{\metre\per\second}$ and $E_{\omega_{\text{S/C}}} < \SI{0.02}{degree}$.}
    \label{tab:results}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % paragraph column with text vertically aligned at the top horizontally aligned at center
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} %  paragraph column with text vertically aligned in the middle horizontally aligned at center
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}r{#1}}  %% right aligned
    \begin{tabular}{
    c %col1 L-point  %option [table-number-alignment = right,center,left]
    S[table-format=4.0] %col2 No. of. sol.
    S[table-format=3.0]%[table-format=2.4,input-decimal-markers=-,output-decimal-marker=-,table-number-alignment = center] %col3 Cand. NEA
    l
    S[table-format=4.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col4
    S[table-format=4.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col5
    S[table-format=4.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col6
    S[table-format=4.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col7
    S[table-format=1.2e1,scientific-notation = true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2] %col8
    S[table-format=6.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col9
    S[table-format=4.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col10
    S[table-format=1.2e1,scientific-notation = true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2] %col11
   }
   \toprule
    \textbf{L} & \multicolumn{1}{M{1cm}}{\textbf{No.of\newline sol.}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{3cm}}{\textbf{Candidate NEA (id. – PDes)}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{2.5cm}}{$\boldsymbol{\Delta V_\mathrm{min}\ –\ \textit{TOF}}$ \textbf{(m/s – day)}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{2.5cm}}{$\boldsymbol{\textit{TOF}_\mathrm{min}\ -\ \Delta V}$ \textbf{(day – m/s)}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{M{3cm}}{$\boldsymbol{E_\mathrm{min}\ – \ d}$  \hspace{0.9cm} \textbf{(deg – km)}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{M{3cm}}{$\boldsymbol{d_\mathrm{min}\ –\ E}$  \hspace{1.0cm} \textbf{(km – deg)}} \\ 
    \cmidrule(){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}\cmidrule(lr){9-10}\cmidrule(l){11-12}
     & 5 & 31 & 2018 PN22  & 495.786955408242 & 321.691007914094 & 321.691007914094 & 495.786955408242 & 0.00766274786981772 & 1304.55816893965 & 1304.55816893965 & 0.00766274786981772 \\
     & 618 & 40 & 2020 HO5 & 296.499238470772 & 563.204937799172 & 460.61389541864  & 434.673022794247 & 1.06333561065898e-06 & 13334.9589039407 & 44.1321628087056 & 0.0043440927667307 \\
     & 207 & 47 & 2021 GM1 & 321.225083304834 & 579.001176279967 & 458.977213170648 & 494.635569509203 & 8.75927739836456e-05 & 16162.8584126721 & 272.790892644318 & 0.000205574640657646 \\
    \multirow{-4}{*}{\num{1}} & 110 & 48 & 2021 LF6 & 331.415081004236 & 547.555702810118 & 426.019758493117 & 494.810189855507 & 0.000659773039856017 & 15282.6573179668 & 1635.52986610854 & 0.00604210949390045 \\ \midrule
    & 188 & 36 & 2020 CD3 & 441.087426101912 & 598.687300827277 & 560.12998365025  & 498.671715102102 & 4.00652387797866e-05 & 720.645461262528 & 226.148958936483 & 0.00124800816293013 \\
    & 150 & 37 & 2020 FA1 & 363.833486907914 & 617.815224738438 & 532.434130120624 & 477.043833738971 & 0.000151649146744098 & 4570.03421246898 & 542.710633669257 & 0.00217371251138835 \\
    & 277 & 39 & 2020 HF4 & 325.869742616378 & 620.47407865956 & 495.241518020061  & 490.112884848913 & 3.56238695777137e-05 & 9221.76907418505 & 316.676948047764 & 0.00396990356158546 \\
    & 30 & 41 & 2020 MU1  & 462.893611205412 & 597.439526870574 & 543.014823292621 & 496.958058852358 & 0.000488508198589889 & 13825.1797358252 & 1772.22939016773 & 0.00367089047771314 \\
    & 373 & 44 & 2020 WY  & 258.567622278901 & 592.325909750424 & 457.543641043238 & 486.364970362706 & 5.77400555816601e-05 & 4916.39967823924 & 12.7440192334999 & 0.000402576106298293 \\
    & 823 & 45 & 2021 AK5 & 150.275430032146 & 690.288217497001 & 553.108214337696 & 490.073643361243 & 1.7294477167511e-05 & 2102.12134797594 & 168.651739286611 & 0.000968271504982416 \\
    & 106 & 49 & 2021 RZ3 & 422.216662637048 & 503.142619476216 & 412.861217455181 & 497.744537876508 & 3.17739132722177e-05 & 15816.5130302721 & 1010.29185702609 & 0.00513171449630041 \\
    & 1161 & 50 & 2021 RG12 & 60.0534121618513 & 469.018823203997 & 310.079915873532 & 483.83013103322 & 3.9138194517227e-06 & 1211.60680842878 & 24.9984223871349 & 0.000221411870262754 \\
    \multirow{-9}{*}{\num{2}}  & 177 & 52 & 2021 VX22 & 428.923740467692 & 370.203538028964 & 346.732351012621 & 496.774800147814 & 9.50215401351551e-05 & 155.225383516442 & 155.225383516442 & 9.50215401351551e-05 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate text block borders)

You only need to insert new row where you put desired column headers.

**Edit:**
For unknown reason copied equation in the first row doesn't work as should be. I need to retype it from scratch.

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Simulation results for $\Delta V < \SI{500}{\metre\per\second}$ and $E_{\omega_{\text{S/C}}} < \SI{0.02}{degree}$.}
    \label{tab:results}
%    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
%    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % paragraph column with text vertically aligned at the top horizontally aligned at center
%    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} %  paragraph column with text vertically aligned in the middle horizontally aligned at center
%    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}r{#1}}  %% right aligned
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{@{} 
    c %col1 L-point  %option [table-number-alignment = right,center,left]
    S[table-format=4.0] %col2 No. of. sol.
    S[table-format=2.0]%[table-format=2.4,input-decimal-markers=-,output-decimal-marker=-,table-number-alignment = center] %col3 Cand. NEA
    l
    S[table-format=3.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col4
    S[table-format=3.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col5
    S[table-format=3.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col6
    S[table-format=3.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col7
    S[table-format=1.2e3,scientific-notation = true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2] %col8
    S[table-format=5.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col9
    S[table-format=4.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col10
    S[table-format=1.2e3,scientific-notation = true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2] %col11
    @{}}
   \toprule
\textbf{L}
    &   {\textbf{No.}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Cand. NEA}} %idate
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\Delta V_{\min}}-\mathit{TOF}$}
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\mathit{TOF}_{\min} - \boldsymbol{\Delta V}$}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\boldsymbol{E_{\min} - d}$}
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\boldsymbol{d_{\min} -  E_{\min}}$}     \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}\cmidrule(lr){9-10}\cmidrule(l){11-12}
     & {\textbf{sol.}}
        & \textbf{id}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{PDes}}
            & \textbf{m/s}  & {\textbf{day}}
                & \textbf{day}  & {\textbf{m/s}}
                    & \textbf{deg}  & {\textbf{km}}
                        &   \textbf{km}  & {\textbf{deg}}     \\

    \midrule
     & 5 & 31 & 2018 PN22  & 495.786955408242 & 321.691007914094 & 321.691007914094 & 495.786955408242 & 0.00766274786981772 & 1304.55816893965 & 1304.55816893965 & 0.00766274786981772 \\
     & 618 & 40 & 2020 HO5 & 296.499238470772 & 563.204937799172 & 460.61389541864  & 434.673022794247 & 1.06333561065898e-06 & 13334.9589039407 & 44.1321628087056 & 0.0043440927667307 \\
     & 207 & 47 & 2021 GM1 & 321.225083304834 & 579.001176279967 & 458.977213170648 & 494.635569509203 & 8.75927739836456e-05 & 16162.8584126721 & 272.790892644318 & 0.000205574640657646 \\
\multirow{-4}{*}{\num{1}} & 110 & 48 & 2021 LF6 & 331.415081004236 & 547.555702810118 & 426.019758493117 & 494.810189855507 & 0.000659773039856017 & 15282.6573179668 & 1635.52986610854 & 0.00604210949390045 \\
    \midrule
    & 188 & 36 & 2020 CD3 & 441.087426101912 & 598.687300827277 & 560.12998365025  & 498.671715102102 & 4.00652387797866e-05 & 720.645461262528 & 226.148958936483 & 0.00124800816293013 \\
    & 150 & 37 & 2020 FA1 & 363.833486907914 & 617.815224738438 & 532.434130120624 & 477.043833738971 & 0.000151649146744098 & 4570.03421246898 & 542.710633669257 & 0.00217371251138835 \\
    & 277 & 39 & 2020 HF4 & 325.869742616378 & 620.47407865956 & 495.241518020061  & 490.112884848913 & 3.56238695777137e-05 & 9221.76907418505 & 316.676948047764 & 0.00396990356158546 \\
    & 30 & 41 & 2020 MU1  & 462.893611205412 & 597.439526870574 & 543.014823292621 & 496.958058852358 & 0.000488508198589889 & 13825.1797358252 & 1772.22939016773 & 0.00367089047771314 \\
    & 373 & 44 & 2020 WY  & 258.567622278901 & 592.325909750424 & 457.543641043238 & 486.364970362706 & 5.77400555816601e-05 & 4916.39967823924 & 12.7440192334999 & 0.000402576106298293 \\
    & 823 & 45 & 2021 AK5 & 150.275430032146 & 690.288217497001 & 553.108214337696 & 490.073643361243 & 1.7294477167511e-05 & 2102.12134797594 & 168.651739286611 & 0.000968271504982416 \\
    & 106 & 49 & 2021 RZ3 & 422.216662637048 & 503.142619476216 & 412.861217455181 & 497.744537876508 & 3.17739132722177e-05 & 15816.5130302721 & 1010.29185702609 & 0.00513171449630041 \\
    & 1161 & 50 & 2021 RG12 & 60.0534121618513 & 469.018823203997 & 310.079915873532 & 483.83013103322 & 3.9138194517227e-06 & 1211.60680842878 & 24.9984223871349 & 0.000221411870262754 \\
    \multirow{-9}{*}{\num{2}}  & 177 & 52 & 2021 VX22 & 428.923740467692 & 370.203538028964 & 346.732351012621 & 496.774800147814 & 9.50215401351551e-05 & 155.225383516442 & 155.225383516442 & 9.50215401351551e-05 \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
%    }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
For exercise, the same table written by use of `tabularray` and `bm` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf
            ]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Simulation results for $\Delta V < \qty{500}{\metre\per\second}$ and $E_{\omega_{\text{S/C}}} < \qty{0.02}{degree}$.}
    \label{tab:results}
\sisetup{table-format=3.0,
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision=0,
         tight-spacing}
    \scriptsize
\begin{tblr}{%
    colsep = 3.1pt,
    colspec = {@{}
                Q[l,m] %col 1
                Q[m, si={table-format=4.0}] %col 2 No. of. sol.
                Q[m, si={table-format=2.0}] %col 3 Cand. NEA
                Q[l,m]     %col 4
                X[m, si]   %col 5
                X[m, si]   %col 6
                X[m, si]   %col 7
                X[m, si]   %col 8
                Q[m, si={table-format=1.2e3,
                         scientific-notation = true,
                         round-precision=2}] %col 9
                Q[m, si={table-format=5.0}]  %col 10
                Q[m, si]   %col 11
                Q[m, si={table-format=1.2e3,
                         scientific-notation = true,
                         round-precision=2}] %col 12
               @{}},
    rowsep = 1pt,
    row{1} = {guard, font=\bfseries, mode=math},
    row{2} = {guard, font=\bfseries, c}
            }
   \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{mode=text}    L   
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{mode=text}      {No. \\   sol.}
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}   \text{Cand. NEA}
            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    \bm{\Delta V_{\min}} - \mathit{TOF}
                    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    \mathit{TOF}_{\min} - \bm{\Delta V}
                        &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    \bm{E_{\min} - d}
                            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    \bm{d_{\min} -  E_{\min}}      
                                    &           \\
   \cmidrule[lr]{3-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-6}  \cmidrule[lr]{7-8}
   \cmidrule[lr]{9-10}\cmidrule[lr]{11-12}
    &   & id    & \SetCell{c}   PDes
            & m/s   & day 
                & day   & m/s 
                    & deg   & km
                        & km    & deg           \\

    \midrule
\SetCell[r=4]{l}   1
    & 5     & 31 & 2018 PN22        & 495.786955408242      & 321.691007914094 & 321.691007914094 
                 & 495.786955408242 & 0.00766274786981772   & 1304.55816893965 & 1304.55816893965 
                 & 0.00766274786981772   \\
    & 618   & 40 & 2020 HO5         & 296.499238470772      & 563.204937799172 & 460.61389541864  
                 & 434.673022794247 & 1.06333561065898e-06  & 13334.9589039407 & 44.1321628087056 
                 & 0.0043440927667307   \\
    & 207   & 47 & 2021 GM1         & 321.225083304834      & 579.001176279967 & 458.977213170648 
                 & 494.635569509203 & 8.75927739836456e-05  & 16162.8584126721 & 272.790892644318 
                 & 0.000205574640657646 \\
    & 110 & 48   & 2021 LF6         & 331.415081004236      & 547.555702810118 & 426.019758493117 
                 & 494.810189855507 & 0.000659773039856017  & 15282.6573179668 & 1635.52986610854 
                 & 0.00604210949390045 \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=9]{l}   2
    & 188 & 36  & 2020 CD3          & 441.087426101912      & 598.687300827277 & 560.12998365025  
                & 498.671715102102  & 4.00652387797866e-05  & 720.645461262528 & 226.148958936483 
                & 0.00124800816293013 \\
    & 150 & 37  & 2020 FA1          & 363.833486907914      & 617.815224738438 & 532.434130120624 
                & 477.043833738971  & 0.000151649146744098  & 4570.03421246898 & 542.710633669257 
                & 0.00217371251138835 \\
    & 277 & 39  & 2020 HF4          & 325.869742616378      & 620.47407865956  & 495.241518020061  
                & 490.112884848913  & 3.56238695777137e-05  & 9221.76907418505 & 316.676948047764 
                & 0.00396990356158546 \\
    & 30 & 41   & 2020 MU1          & 462.893611205412      & 597.439526870574 & 543.014823292621 
                & 496.958058852358  & 0.000488508198589889  & 13825.1797358252 & 1772.22939016773 
                & 0.00367089047771314 \\
    & 373 & 44  & 2020 WY           & 258.567622278901      & 592.325909750424 & 457.543641043238 
                & 486.364970362706  & 5.77400555816601e-05  & 4916.39967823924 & 12.7440192334999 
                & 0.000402576106298293 \\
    & 823 & 45  & 2021 AK5          & 150.275430032146      & 690.288217497001 & 553.108214337696 
                & 490.073643361243  & 1.7294477167511e-05   & 2102.12134797594 & 168.651739286611 
                & 0.000968271504982416 \\
    & 106 & 49  & 2021 RZ3          & 422.216662637048      & 503.142619476216 & 412.861217455181 
                & 497.744537876508  & 3.17739132722177e-05  & 15816.5130302721 & 1010.29185702609
                & 0.00513171449630041 \\
    & 1161 & 50 & 2021 RG12         & 60.0534121618513      & 469.018823203997 & 310.079915873532 
                & 483.83013103322   & 3.9138194517227e-06   & 1211.60680842878 & 24.9984223871349
                & 0.000221411870262754 \\
    & 177 & 52  & 2021 VX22         & 428.923740467692      & 370.203538028964 & 346.732351012621 
                & 496.774800147814  & 9.50215401351551e-05  & 155.225383516442 & 155.225383516442
                & 9.50215401351551e-05 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Zarko. The result is almost ok, can you remove the `\cmdrule` of first two columns and vertically center in the cell the header of first column, i.e. `L`?

Comment: @Giuseppe, of course I can. But why you not do this yourself? As I can delete undesired `\cmidrule{...}` from code  you can do this too.

Comment: @Giuseppe, INow I observe that math term in the first row doesn't work as should be, So rewrote it from scratch and now result is correct. By the way I also delete  undesired `\cmidrule` (what you could  do yourself) .

Comment: Thank you @Zarko. Can you also help me to vertically center the header of the first column (i.e. `L`)?

Comment: @Giuseppe, see addendum to answer. For the first example, just use `\multirow`. It is time, that such simple things do yourself. If you will not try, you will never learn wite of table. It may help you to read some introductory text about table. For example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.

Comment: @Giuseppe, sorry for spelling errors in above comment: wite --> write, table --> tables.